# NotSerializableException only first time

Tags: java, objectoutputstream, notserializableexception

I get a NotSerializableException in objStream.writeObject(myobj) only the first time.

myobj internally contains a list of objects.
The same myobj, when its not the first one, serializes fine.
Any ideas please?
Code looks somewhat like this:

```
public class MyObj implements Serializable 
{
   private List<MyOtherObjects> objects;
};

for (myobj : myobjs) {
                byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutputStream);
                objStream.writeObject (myobj);
                objStream.flush(); 
                objStream.close();
                file.write(byteOutputStream.toByteArray());
...
```

Stack trace:

```
DoCompute flush thread [XRXTransactionQueue-1-1402065645208--1569561033][1] where
  [1] java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0 (ObjectOutputStream.java:1,156)
  [2] java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields (ObjectOutputStream.java:1,509)
  [3] java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData (ObjectOutputStream.java:1,474)
  [4] java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:1,392)
  [5] java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0 (ObjectOutputStream.java:1,150)
  [6] java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject (ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
  [7] utils.DoCompute$FileHandler.flush (DoCompute.java:678)
```

Comment: Can you add a stacktrace

Comment: aah my bad! - it is in writeObject() - but why does it happen only first time. Modifying and adding stack trace

Comment: What does when its not the first one means? If you serialise the same objects in different order, does it work for you, can you add code for this?

Comment: That doesn't look like any stacktrace I've seen before. Where is the exception listed? Try and create a *minimal example* that compiles and demonstrates this problem.

Comment: Thats jdb stack trace. I meant, it only throws an exception for the first myobj - its not a specific myobj that has a problem. If I serialize in different order, its still first one that fails. I cant create a small example - if I could, it would be more obvious. Just wondering if it means anything that it always happens with first object.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have some of MyOtherObjects, not implementing Serializable, the fact that MyObj implements Serializable, does not guarantee, that it could actually be Serialized, not unless all of it's members, can be serialized as well.

Check the hierarchy of MyOtherObjects, there you should find some unserializable object.